# Excel VBA Copying data with date error

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Hi recently i have generated a csv data file using Foxpro 7.0. So I were going to use VBA to copy the data from A.csv to the reporting excel file B in the format of xlsm.

```
Workbooks("A")
Range("A2:AB300000").Copy
Workbooks("B").Activate
Sheets("C").Select
Range("B6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Workbooks("A").Close
```

and there are multiples files for me to copy.
My problem is I got different type of results in the date column, which contains randomly generated US/UK date with either general or date format.
Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: You've not explained a problem or asked a specific question. What exactly is the problem? You say *error* but never explain the error or provide an error message, and you say *Please help* but haven't asked a question. See [ask] and [mcve], and then [edit] your post to more clearly explain what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is that the columns which contain the date were randomly wrong. The dates are supposed to be in UK format. However, once i use VBA to copy, some dates are normal, some of them are in US format, some are in general form.

Comment: One method:  Assuming the original generated .csv file is UK format dates, you need to `import` the CSV file into Excel.  If you `open` the file, Excel will parse the date according to the Windows Regional short date settings.  If they are not UK settings, you will see the issue you describe.  If you `Import` the file, the text import wizard will open, and you can define the date setting for interpretation.

Comment: As I said, you need to [edit] your post and explain the problem more clearly. We can't see the data, you didn't provide any samples, your code is incomplete, and your problem description is unclear. Please read my last comment again, visit the links I provided, and then (again) come back and [edit] your question. Notice I did not say *Leave another comment*, but specifically (and for about the fourth time) said [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code.

```
Sub TransToXLSFromCSV()
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim vDB
Dim fn As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim i As Long
Dim Wb As Workbook
    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Csv Files *.csv,*.csv;*.csv", _
      Title:="Select the Csv Files!", MultiSelect:=True)
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To UBound(vFile)
        fn = Dir(vFile(i))
        fn = Left(fn, Len(fn) - 4)

         Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=vFile(i), Format:=2)
         vDB = Wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
         Wb.Close
         Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
         With Wb
            .ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
            .SaveAs Filename:=strPath & "\" & fn & ".xlsx"
            .Close (0)
         End With
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```